# After-Before pseudo in CSS3 for multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

How to assign after & before pseudo classes to multiple CSS-classes

**For example:**

```
[class*="divclass-"]::before, ::after{
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 30%;
      height : 30%;
      border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this HTML structure, where you have a `<div>` which have children `<span>` and `<p>`. And another `<span>` and `<p>` as siblings.

```
<div>
  <span>abc</span>
  <p>xyz</p>
</div>
<span>123</span>
<p>456</p>
```

For example, if we need to change the colour of the children, we could write on your way,

```
div span, p{
  color: red;
}
```

This problem with this is that, it will change the colour of the sibling `<p>456</p>` too as the style is applied globally to all the paragraph tags.

And the solution is to follow specificity as we did with the `<span>` and write the selectors as

```
div span, 
div p{
  color: red;
}
```

The same rule applies to pseudo-elements as well. Hence the **solution** is,

```
[class*="divclass-"]::before, 
[class*="divclass-"]::after{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height : 30%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

> Note 1

If you are working on SASS, your syntax could be,

```
[class*="divclass-"]{
  &::before, 
  &::after{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30%;
    height : 30%;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
}
```

> Note 2

The `before` and `after` pesudo-elements require the `content` property.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The comma does not mean that the following elements are children of the same selector (here [class*="divclass-"]). 
It just allows you to chain the selectors.

@see https://www.thoughtco.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052

Here is the solution:

```css
[class*="divclass-"]::before, 
[class*="divclass-"]::after {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 30%;
      height : 30%;
      border: 3px solid red;
      content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="divclass-1" style="height: 10px; width: 10px"></div>
```